# Extract all words from a sentence ending in an expression using R

Tags: r, regex

suppose I have the next string:

"palavras a serem encontradas fazer-se encontrar-se, enganar-se"

How can I extract the words "fazer-se" "encontrar-se" "enganar-se"

I'm try o use stringr like

```
library(stringr)    
sentence <- "palavras a serem encontradas fazer-se encontrar-se, enganar-se"
str_extract_all(sentence, "se$")
```

I'd like this output:

```
[1] "fazer-se" "encontrar-se" "enganar-se"
```

Comment: Use `str_extract_all(sentence, "\\w+-se\\b")`

Answer (score 2):

We can specify the word boundary (`\\b`) and not the end (`$`) of the string (there is only one match for that, i.e. at the end of the string)  and we need to get the characters that are not a whitespace before the `se` substring, so use `\\S+` i.e. one or more non-whitespace characters

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(sentence, "\\S+se\\b")[[1]]
#[1] "fazer-se"     "encontrar-se" "enganar-se"
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can use `gregexpr` and `regmatches` :

```
regmatches(sentence, gregexpr('\\w+-se', sentence))[[1]]
#[1] "fazer-se"     "encontrar-se" "enganar-se"
```